# lsyncd for files-mirroring at localhost: Parameter "targetdir" unknown

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to use lsync for mirroring files. Either source and target files located at localhost.
This is settings:

```
 settings {
   logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
   statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status",
   statusInterval = 5,
   insist = true
  }

sync {
   default.rsync,
   delete = false,
   delay = 3,
   source = "/home/andrej/infodiod/source",
   host = localhost,
   targetdir = "/home/andrej/infodiod/targetdir",
   rsync = {
   archive = true,
   compress = true,
   _extra = { "--remove-source-files" }
    }
 }
```

But trynig to run lsyncd, I receive the following error:

```
Parameter "targetdir" unknown
```

Access rights for targetdir:
drwxr-xr-x
Setting-file located at /etc

And I dont see any logs at lsyncd.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check are you using default.rsync instead of default.rsyncssh

Read this: [lsync documentation](https://axkibe.github.io/lsyncd/manual/config/layer4/)

Comment: Yes, thank you! Instead of using "target", as shoul be applied for localhost, I used "targetdir"-parameter (for remote)